# Passing information from an existing record, to a new record, of a different table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clone

If I have `Table A` with columns `title` and `description`, and I want to create a record in `Table B`, which also has a `title` and `description` column, is there a way to pass that information to `new_b_path` such that the /views/b/_form.html.erb populates with the data from the `A` record?

I am using the below code to `clone` a `workout` but this is acting within `Table A` so to speak. I want to `clone` across tables. Any ideas?

workouts_controller.rb

```
...
  def new
    @workout_count = Workout.count
    if params[:cloned_workout]
        workout_to_clone = Workout.find params[:cloned_workout]
        @workout = workout_to_clone.clone
      else
    @workout = current_user.workouts.new 
  end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @workout }
    end
  end
...
```

/views/workouts/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Clone Workout", new_workout_url + "?cloned_workout=#{@workout.id}", :class => "float-right" %>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need 2 tables?

Comment: I have `workouts` (table A) and then I allow a gym to post a `recommended_workout` (table B). I want gym members to be able to clone the `recommended_workout` into their own workout log. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. Judging by your explanation it sounds like a better strategy might be to simply create a table called Recommended with two belongs_to relationships that just has a workout_id and user_id column. Then you can associate the recommendation to a user and the workout. You could also have a gym_id or trainer_id column for the gym or trainer that made the recommendation. Make sense?

Comment: Maybe `recommended` wasn't the best term to use. Perhaps `posted` would have been better. Imagine that there is a `/gyms/show.html.erb` page and on that page the gym owner can post a Workout. The members (users) could come to `/gyms/1` and see the posted workout, and clone it (taking it to the `workouts_new` action.

Comment: Ok, I see, so linking to possibly ethereal entries could cause a problem if those posted workouts somehow got removed by the originator.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if using "clone" is a bit too restrictive for your needs. Maybe try just creating the new object using the old one's attributes. 

`@workout = current_user.workouts.new(:description => workout_to_clone.description, :title => workout_to_clone.title)`